# Copy a filtered Excelsheet into a multi array in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, multidimensional-array, filter

I have read here and there something about SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible), but I don't manage to get it into the code.
I want to copy a filtered Excel sheet with multiple columns and rows into an array, without using a new sheet to copy it from.

For the moment is this my code (for an unfiltered sheet):

```
    For i = 1 To LastRow
        For j = 1 To 9
        strArray(i, j) = Cells(i, j).Value2
        Next j
    Next i
```

Any hints or clues how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes I am not so good in thinking. To check for hidden rows gave me the answer! This did the trick!

```
    k = 1
For i = 1 To LastRow
    For j = 1 To 9
    If Sheets("Feuil2").Rows(i).Hidden = False Then
    strArray(k, j) = Cells(i, j).Value2
    Else
    End If
    Next j
    If Sheets("Feuil2").Rows(i).Hidden = False Then
    k = k + 1
    Else
    End If
Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like this :

```
strArray= Sheets(Sheet_name).AutoFilter.Range.Value
```

And you have convert a Range to an Array!

Comment: The idea is good, but it takes all the values and not the filtered ones (on date).

Comment: And with strArray = Sheets("Feuil2").AutoFilter.Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Value it only takes the first visible cells. So probably it has to become a kind of loop.

Comment: What do you mean by "first visible cells"? first row? It's strange though... because I use `ShF.AutoFilter.Range.Columns(ColRef).Value` and it works just fine...

Comment: Did you filter a part of your data? I first sort the data on name and after that on date. So I got 38 rows with the first name on date and than another part with the second name. So 1-38 and than 129-218 and so on. So your code cuts after 38. Here they find the same: http://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/autofilter-range-visible-cells-to-array.1020620/

Comment: I'll be careful with mine because it doesn't seem to work elsewhere!^^
Does the `.Count` property give you 38 after filter? Did you try to go through rows and test if visible? Or you can try to use `MS Forms 2.0 Object Library` (if you don't find it, look for fm20.dll on disk and add it in References) and use `GetFromClipboard` and `PutInClipboard` functions (I'm short on time and will have some tomorrow to continue to help)